# Remove loading text on Silverstripe

Tags: loading, gif, silverstripe

Does anyone know how to remove the default text that says "Loading..." that shows up next to your GIF in Silverstripe?

I uploaded a new GIF and now I just want to show that and remove the loading bit.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `CMSLoadingScreen.ss` template file and put it in `mysite/templates`.

If you need custom CSS with that, you can require that within your template, or via config file (eg. `mysite/_config/config.yml`)

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - my/path/to/styles.css
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#> find framework/ -type f -name '*.yml' | xargs grep -H 'Loading...'
...
framework/lang/en.yml:    LOADING: Loading...
...
```

I had thought you could just override under the mysite dir thus (SS 3.2)

In **mysite/lang/en/en.yml**

```
en:
  CMSLoadingScreen_ss:
    LOADING: 'Please wait...'
```

...but it didn't work for calls to `_t()` in templates (It should work for backend (PHP) calling logic though)

To allow templates to see your change, you need to drop a `lang/en` (for example) dir under your `templates/my-project` folder.

..you'll also need to clear the SilverStripe cache by doing the usual call to ?flush=all in your browser.